# Accused of "tag abuse"

Tags: discussion, tags, formatting

I've asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45298469/revisions) and the made a tag of the first occurrences of some topics/components, because it is possible that not everyone which can help me knows about all of the components playing a role in my question.

I figured that formatting this as a tag would allow people to hover over them and read the description of it at a glance.

A few minutes later, my post is edited with a message that I *abuse* tags (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45298469/2). This comes across as quite harsh and I really find the tags beneficial to my question, and only a few tags exist..

Did I really **abuse** tags? I never read in the help section that this method of using tags is abusing them, how should I feel about this?

Comment: What they mean by abuse is an over-use of formatting that doesn't fit in running text. It makes it difficult to read. You could possibly, if you really want, add the tags to the bottom of your question but keep the text as text for legibility.

Comment: IMO there is no real value in setting tags in the question _body_.. They should be added _as tags_ in the bottom for filtering and searching. I would have edited it out too..

Comment: @suraj I have added a comment to BoltClock's answer why in my opinion it could provide value.

Comment: @ManeatingKoala you should read the answer posted by Glorfindel. That should answer your comment

Comment: *You* may find the tags beneficial to your question, but people with screen readers (because of bad eyesight) will disagree.

Answer (score 13):

> I figured that formatting this as a tag would allow people to hover over them and read the description of it at a glance.

You should assume that readers of your question are at least familiar enough with the technologies involved to not need a primer on them. Having these tags just clutters up your question and makes it unnecessarily hard to read for your target audience, who are more than likely familiar with the subject matter already.

Maybe we do need a help page describing when exactly to use tag formatting. Generally, you only use it when you want to refer to a tag (which in turn means that you generally use tag formatting only on meta). You don't use it to turn a keyword that happens to be a tag into a link to the tag.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but for example people who know about php, xdebug and phpunit might be perfectly able to answer my question while not knowing what phpstorm is. If phpstorm is a tag, then they can just hover over it and quickly read the description. "phpstorm" sounds like some php function and people might know assume it's an IDE.

Comment: @ManeatingKoala And these people can't hover that tag at the buttom of the page, because ....? Sorry, but that isn't a good excuse to worsen the text readability.

Comment: @Maneating Koala: Or, for that matter, Google it in their own time.

Comment: Sorry I offended people by adding a tag, I will stop harassing them.

Comment: I don't think anyone feels offended or harassed, but whatever you say.

Answer (score 3):

> I figured that formatting this as a tag would allow people to hover over them and read the description of it at a glance.

While this is an honorable attempt, this *should* not work because the tag wiki excerpts are being misused. Tag wiki excerpts **should not explain what a certain term means**; one of the rejection reasons for suggested edits to tag wiki excerpts is:

> #### lacks usage guidance
>
> Simply defining what a [tag] *is* rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

Also, if users really need to look up what certain technologies mean, they're either not qualified to answer the question, or *the technology is irrelevant to the question* and you should concentrate on writing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it is a question, not a tag wiki, right?

Comment: @rene yes. Let me rephrase: if everybody used tag wiki excerpts as intended, the 'hovers' wouldn't be useful to readers of the question.

Comment: My casual reading style missed that nuance...